# why do we need to assign ΔH =0 for the formation of aqueous hydrogen ions?

Tags: thermodynamics

Many books state that the enthalpy of formation of aqueous hydrogen ions is 0 BY DEFINITION, and hydrogen is chosen just for convenience. Once we do that, all other reactions have their enthalpies defined relative to this.

My question is, why do we even need to define it for a particular reaction? Shouldn't the enthalpy change be defined for every reaction, without the need to define one arbitrarily as 0?

we know that it takes 13.6 ev/atom to excite its electron. so why isnt this considered here?

Edit: There are similar questions with answers explaining why HYDROGEN is taken as 0. my question is why we must define zero at all

Comment: Reactions are a different matter altogether. I thought you were talking about ions.

Comment: Enthalpy of formation being zero by definition is for elements in their standard states,i.e. H2(g) in the hydrogen case.

Comment: @Poutnik This is about ions, not elements (or so it seems).

Comment: @IvanNeretin I know. But I do not remember if I have ever heard the formation enthalpy of hydrated H+ is 0, even by definition. It would mean total enthalpy change of atomisation, ionization and ion hydration is zero by definition too.

Comment: @Poutnik This definition does exist, though. You can't measure the enthalpy of _one_ ion the same way you do for compounds, because no compound consists of just one ion. So we define (somewhat arbitrarily) DeltaH(H+) = 0 and work out the enthalpies of all other ions from there.

Comment: @IvanNeretin That makes sense.

Comment: @Poutnik To you, yes. To the OP, probably not so much. And now the discussion is too extended, and it has not even started. _"My tale was heard and yet it was not told."_

Answer (score 1):

Heat effects accompanying half-reactions are impossible to measure. In order for heat effects to be determined, a reaction must be carried out, and two half-reactions have to be combined. So if a heat effect has to be given to any half-reaction, the heat effect of at least one of these half-reactions must be arbitrarily chosen.

The same reasoning is used for defining the redox potentials. Individual redox potentials cannot be measured. Only differences of potentials can. This is why one of these potentials must be arbitrarily defined. So the chemists fixed the redox potential of Hydrogen at $\pu{0 V}$. Hydrogen was chosen because it was already the reference for atomic masses in the beginning of the 20th century.

Comment: but why dont we consider the fact that I takes 13.6 ev per atom to remove an electron?

Comment: Heat of formation is defined through making the species from the elements. You can't make hydrogen ions from hydrogen without also getting an electron. For uncharged species, you can make the species (and just the species) from elements.

Comment: I repeat. The enthalpy change or the electric  potential of a half reaction is impossible to determine in solution. Of course 13.4 eV is needed to remove an electron from a H atom  in a vacuum, but not in solution. The heat of formation of $\ce{H+}$ can not be determined alone, because the electron is not emitted in a vacuum. It is emitted from a $\ce{H2}$ molecule. As soon as it has been removed from the $\ce{H2) molecule, it is absorbed by a foreign molecule or a foreign ion like $\ce{Ag^{+}$, without passing through an intermediate state where it is free.

Comment: Hydrogen while chosen by Dalton was never the accepted standard for atomic masses. Oxygen was chosen in 1903 and refined when its isotopes were discovered that resulted in two scales that were unified when C-12 was chosen to placate chemists. Today Avogadro's number is defined and all atomic masses are empirical altho C-12 comes closest to12. still. read about it here http://sites.science.oregonstate.edu/chemistry/courses/ch121-3s/ch121/Answers%20to%20interesting%20questions/history_of_the_atomic_mass_unit.htm I guess one had to live thru it all to understand what was happening.

Comment: @jimchemist. I perfectly know all what you try to explain to me. I have even taken part to the panel of discussion about the choice or refusal of Hydrogen, Carbon-12 or Oxygen in the years 1980.  I was the delegate of my country. It does not change the fact that in  order to decide which reduction potential would be accepted as a reference, The hydrogen was chosen for historical reasons, related to the old definition of atomic masses.